# Laplacian of composition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $u \in C^2(U)$ with $\Delta u(y)=0$ for all $y \in U.$ Let $\phi: V \rightarrow U$ be in $C^2(U)$, too with $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open. Now, I want to understand what conditions $\Delta u(\phi) = 0,$ too.

A small calculation got me $$\Delta u(\phi(x)) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \partial_i^2 u( \phi(x)) ( \partial_i \phi_i(x))^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \partial_i u (\phi(x)) \partial_i^2\phi_i(x).$$

Unfortunately, I don't really understand what it tells me about $\phi$ if this expression is equal to zero. Is there any way to rewrite this in a more intuitive form?

Comment: Did you try to rewrite it in the vector form, expressing Laplacian as divergence of a gradient? 
$$
\Delta u(\phi) = \nabla\!\cdot\!\nabla \,u(\phi) = \operatorname{div}\!\Big(\!\operatorname{grad}\big(u(\phi) \big)  \Big)
$$
Don't forget to make use of the [multidimensional chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_as_a_derivative).

Comment: Are you interested in conditions on $\phi$ that imply $\Delta(u\circ \phi)=0$ for _every_ harmonic function $u$, or for some particular harmonic function $u$?

Comment: @Yes for every...